# Fastest method to save pageviews in database with doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Using Symfony 4 with doctrine, I want to save pageviews for one entity `Program` in the database. I want to save this to the database because I want to give some users the rights to view these numbers. What I have done is add a property to the entity like this:

**Program.php**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $pageViews;

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getPageViews()
{
    return $this->pageViews;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $pageViews
 */
public function setPageViews($pageViews)
{
    $this->pageViews = $pageViews;
}
```

And in my **ProgramController.php** in the function `showProgram`

```
//...
$program->setPageViews($program->getPageViews()+1);
$em->persist($program);
$em->flush();
```

This works and adds 1 to the existing number every time the page is refreshed. My question is, is this an acceptable method or are there faster/better alternatives? And does this slow down performance or is that negligible?

Comment: `public function addPageViews() { ++$this->pageViews; }` might be a bit faster, beside that, I don't see what could be optimised

Comment: You can use doctrines dql lang, so you avoid hydrating entities, so it will be much faster, sth like this - UPDATE MyProject\Model\Program p SET p.pageViews = p.pageViews + 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't really need the entity you could directly do this with SQL, using Doctrine's connection:

```
$connection = $this->getDoctrine()->getConnection();
$connection->executeUpdate('UPDATE page_view_counter SET page_view = page_view+1;');
```

or using a preprared statement:

```
$connection = $this->getDoctrine()->getConnection();
$statement = $connection->prepare(
    'UPDATE programs SET page_views = page_views + 1 WHERE programs.id = :id'
);
$statement->bindValue('id', $id);
$statement->execute();
```

This would speed up things a bit by not using some of the more complex features of the ORM that you don't need for your case.

Another alternative for speeding things up could be to switch technologies, like storing the data in a cache like redis. Whether this will actually improve performance (especially under a heavier load) would need to be verified using some measuring tool like JMeter.

Comment: I do need the entity, because on the page I show I need to show program variables. So I guess in that case my or Cid's solution might be better?

Comment: Yes, for the beginning at least. You still have to be careful as your code might produce race conditions. If user A & B load the site at roughly the same time, let's say 100 page_views, they will both load this value and increment that. Then they will save their value and therefore no matter which of both saves the value last, the counter will probably say 101, instead of 102. With my code, this will not happen because each query updates the value in the database directly instead of loading it first. If you don't mind the chance for this slight variance your solution should work just fine.

Comment: Cid's approach will have the same drawback by the way. As it also loads the value into the entity, updates it and then saves the new entity state to the database. The only way to get around it, is to make the update atomic, by not retrieving it first, but instead doing the +1 directly in the database using SQL.

Comment: Obviously, directly sending SQL query is certainly the best option. This query is simple enough to avoid coupling issues bewteen differents DBMS. Let's hope you don't have fields and table badly named that requires to be wrapped into backticks or brackets

Comment: @dbrumann, one more thing; is there a way to bind a parameter to this SQL? I am trying to save pageviews for each individual program so I am trying something like this now: `$connection->executeUpdate('UPDATE programs SET page_views = page_views+1 WHERE programs.id is :id; ');` I can't however seem to be able to bind a parameter to use it in the query.

Comment: Yes, DBAL also supports parameters: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.8/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#dynamic-parameters-and-prepared-statements. I have added an example to my answer